# OpenVPN with CryptoAPI on Linux

Tags: linux, openvpn, encryption

I have an OpenVPN config file that uses Microsoft CryptoAPI. Meaning, it contains these lines:

```
cryptoapicert "SUBJ:..."
ca ca_file.crt
tls-auth tls.key
```

It works fine on a Windows system. However, when trying to connect via OpenVPN on Linux, it complains that `cryptoapicert` option is unrecognized. Is there any way i can make it work?

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, OpenVPN 2.3.2.

Thanks!